# MySql date-string ORDER

Tags: mysql

*I've edited this post(the problem with a '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s' was like a half)

Still, I don't get it :/
This is working fine and selecting in right 'desc' order:

```
SELECT monitor.data_activity FROM monitor, player WHERE monitor.player_id = player.id AND monitor.player_id = 1
      AND (STR_TO_DATE(monitor.data_activity, '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN '2014-10-31' AND '2014-11-01') 
      ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(monitor.data_activity, '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s')) DESC;
```

But If I change (AND monitor.player_id = 1) to (AND monitor.cord = '1:1:1') where cord is a varchar10

```
SELECT monitor.data_activity FROM monitor, player WHERE monitor.player_id = player.id AND monitor.cord = '1:1:1'
      AND (STR_TO_DATE(monitor.data_activity, '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN '2014-10-31' AND '2014-11-01') 
      ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(monitor.data_activity, '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i:%s')) DESC;
```

And it breaks my ORDER BY:

```
31.10.2014 20:35:27   
01.11.2014 18:20:01   
31.10.2014 00:55:43   
31.10.2014 14:41:17   
31.10.2014 21:07:24    
01.11.2014 19:05:10
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is coincidence.  Both `order by` expressions are only ordering by the date.  In one case, it happens to put the time in the right order as well.  You can just use:

```
order by STR_TO_DATE(monitor.data_activity, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working! My bad that I was trying with a format '%H:%I:%S' instead of yours '%h:%i:%s'.

Comment: @Igor . . . That should be a capital "H" not "h".  And, your format should have worked.

Comment: Any other ideas about that (my new 1st post)?